# Can't use cakephp's assosiation model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

Can't use cakephp's assosiation model

I designed DB model such as image, and coded model assosiation, but couldn't access stoc_wish and ctos_wish model from student model.

```
// student.php
class Student extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Team');
    public $hasMany = array('Stoc_wish', 'Ctos_wish');
}

// stoc_wish.php
class Stoc_wish extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Student', 'Cuser');
}

// ctos_wish.php
class Ctos_wish extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Student', 'Cuser');
}
```

Please give me useful advices.

CakePHP version => 2.6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58qbN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class names in CakePHP 2.x must be camel cased, [as described in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#file-and-class-name-conventions), and must match the underscored version of your table names. If they don't, you have to set the $useTable property in the model.

The same applies to model filenames.

It is important that you follow [CakePHP conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html). The more you adhere to conventions, the less configuration you will need.

Comment: I didn't think naming convention! I can use it now! Thanks!